# Google Chrome input text is cut off. Is it font issue or browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

Please take a look at this page http://s.codepen.io/nfxpnk/debug/akLbwG

As you can see at the first block with pink background, input with value "ÄÄÖÖÜÜ" doesn't have dots on the top.

And that behavior is only then height property on input tag is set.

Is it font issue or google chrome browser bug?

Unfortunately i can't remove height property on my project from all input fields.

How to fix this issue?

PS. Firefox and IE doesn't have this bug.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not happening on chrome on the iPad

Comment: reproducible in Windows 10, Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question. Your testing already shows that this is happening in Chrome, but only when `height` is specified on your input field.  It's clearly a browser issue, and you have a path for resolution (altering the height) though I understand you feel this is not accessible.  Have you considered leaving the `height` intact but reducing the font size?

Comment: Did you try making the height and line-height the same?

Comment: @CarolMcKay yes i did try that, but it doesn't help. actually, the one and only fix for this issue is to remove height from input tag (or to use different font)

Comment: From my experience, non-optimized webfonts will have inconsistencies with line height between browsers and operating systems. By that I mean they'll be too far up or down in the allocated line. The only way around it I've seen is to figure out which browsers are having the issue, targeting them, and changing the line height on a per-case basis

Comment: @RobertC yep, but even if font size is 11px there is no dots on top

Comment: Have you tried box-sizing:border-box; ?

Comment: @CarolMcKay box-sizing:border-box doesn't change the situation with this issue

Comment: min-height? I can't edit your codepen. am going to bed now, good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` to `min-height`

```
font-family: 'adihausregular',Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
min-height: 60px;
line-height: 54px;
width: 100%;
```

It seems that if you want you can also add `max-height: 60px;` and it still works.

Comment: Thanks, i think that it's the only way to make it work right with fixed height value.